# Artifactory local repository with custom layout deploy problem

Tags: regex, artifactory

I'm using [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) (hosted version) to store some cpp libraries we build for multiple platforms.

We use a simple repository with a custom layout configured as follows:

```
Artifact Path Pattern: [org]/[module]/[folderItegRev]/[baseRev]/[platform<macos|linux64|win32|win64|ios|android>]/[module]-[baseRev]-[build<linux64(?:[^-]*)|macos|win32_vs20(?:[0-9]{2})|win64_vs20(?:[0-9]{2})|ios|android(?:[^-]*)>](-[fileItegRev]).[ext]

Folder Integration Revision RegExp:
release|nightly|mr

File Integration Revision RegExp:
r[a-z0-9]+
```

What I am having trouble to understand is why if I upload a package named like

```
myproj/modulename/release/4.6.0/win32/mylib-4.6.0-win32_vs2010-r63c86bd.zip
```

then artifactory (although the artifact is stored in the correct path hyerarchy) from the webgui does not show a valid *module ID* that shows up as *N/A* instead

while if I upload a package like **this** one:

```
myproj/modulename/release/4.6.0/macos/mylib-4.6.0-macos-r63c86bd.zip
```

then I get a *module ID* value of  myproj:module:4.6.0-r63c86bd

This is annoying because the ones with the *N/A* value seems not be first class citizens and then cannot be deleted when cleaning up old versions.

I suppose there must be something wrong either with my regexp or with the layout configuration because the only artifacts uploaded correctly are those for *ios* and *macos* that are the only ones where the *platform* is the same of the *build* custom placeholders, all other build are the like of:

- win32_vs2010
- win32_vs2017
- android_arm64
- linux64_Ubuntu_18.04

etc.